# Wrapper Div Not Centering in IE7,8,9 and FF11 with margin:0 auto

Tags: html, css

I'm putting together a landing page and can't figure out why the wrapper div is not centering in IE. I've tried to set explicit widths on the body and content divs but that didn't work (the width I used was 100% because I need it to expand and contract). I know this is basic HTML but I wasn't doing my cross-browser checks at the beginning so now I'm kinda far in and can't figure out where the issue is.

The URL is here:

http://www.ncfitclub.net/landing/insanity/

I've done cross browser checks and the wrapper doesn't center in IE7,8 and 9 or in Firefox 11 (although it does center in my up to date version of Firefox on my Mac). I'm also not getting the background image in the content div to repeat-x. My assumption is that this is a width issue (which would explain why I don't see the background image on the content div) but I'm out of ideas on how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: does the wrapper div have a parent? and if it does is it set to `position: relative;`?

Comment: The wrapper does have a parent div and I've set it to position:relative but that shouldn't be the issue since I've done site in the past that don't require that.